# Google Maps api v3 (Javascript): Image in infowindow

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, infowindow

I am trying to build a website and I want to have a map that has several markers (with different color) filtered with a checkbox. I am working on this example:

http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_MW_example_categories.html

I have already changed it a little bit and I removed the sidebar. It works great for me but it s a bit confusing how I will put an image in the infowindow. I want to have an image in the size of a thumbnail and a small comment into the infowindow. This example has an external xml file http://www.geocodezip.com/categories.xml with a tag  and several attributes like name, id, address, category. 
Also it uses an external js file but this doesn t bother me.

I was thinking about making an array named content and put there the images, and call it in the for (line 195). Something like making a new variable named content (); and adding it to the var html (); (line 202). But it won' t work. I also thought of putting an attribute on  name "photo", for example.But then the map doesn t even show on the page.

Obviously I am not a programmer, and my skills are not very good. If anyone has a clue on this, I would appreciate it!! Sorry for my english too. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can write the page for you, but what fun would that be? ;)

First, the markers can be obtained from here:

https://sites.google.com/site/gmapsdevelopment/ Ctrl-Find "ms/micons".

There's also [Google Chart Icons](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/infographics/docs/dynamic_icons.html) but that's now deprecated.

I recommend looking at [this page](http://www.wolfpil.de/v3/toggle-cats.html). It has the checkboxes that are grouped and you can remove the content you don't need, like you mentioned, the sidebar. The trick is it uses Ajax to retrieve the marker info from [this xml](http://www.wolfpil.de/markers-muenchen.xml). You could follow the same approach, or just make arrays of data straight in the JavaScript file.

About the image in the InfoWindow, just place an "img src" tag in the html of myInfoWindow.setContent(html). If you can show where it went wrong I'll take a look. When the map doesn't show, usually there's a JavaScript error that your browser console will tell you. (Firebug in Firefox, Ctrl+Shift+I or F12 in Chrome)

Comment: Thanks for the answer!!!... Actually, i have downloaded my markers and saved them locally, i can t place an "img src" tag on the infowindow.setContent(html) because if it work it will work for only one pisture and i was a different foto for each infowindow... I want to have a different image for each marker. The example seems very simple and useful thought!!! :) Thanks again!

Comment: @JavascriptGeek If you can display different text in each infowindow you should be able to get different images. There IS a head-scratching "feature" of Javascript that if you are creating them in a for loop, wrapping a (function(i) { ... })(i); around the creation will correct the behavior. Try the approach in the file I linked, you should be able to get multiple images. Even then if you'd like I'll help with the pictures in infowindows, you can edit your question and post another comment here to alert me.

Comment: Lillina, I just did it!! Thank you!! Unfortunately i am a new member and i can t leave a rep :( Cheers and thanks again for the help!

Comment: @JavascriptGeek Way to go!! Thanks for accepting my answer and nudged you a bit closer to being able to vote up :) You're always welcome here!

Answer (score 1):

Creating custom markers with images can be done [here](http://powerhut.co.uk/googlemaps/custom_markers.php).

Comment: Was looking for something like this from a long time. Tx